# Outlook 2019: Button does not show up in Home Ribbon

Tags: outlook-addin

I am writing an Outlook 2019 add-in for which I would like to place a button on the home tab.  I am using ribbon xml and I am able to get this to successfully appear on the AddIns and View tab.  However, I cannot get it to appear on the Home tab.  This is my XML:

```
<tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabHome">
    <group id="ContentGroup" label="Custom Content">
      <button id="textButton" label="Custom Button" screentip="Text" onAction="MethodCall"/>
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

If I change "TabHome" to "TabView" then the button shows up at the end of the ribbon perfectly.  Is there a special trick to making this work? Is the idMso of "TabHome" correct for outlook 2019?

Finally, what is the idMso for the "Message" tab when you're in a separate window with an email?

Answer (score 2):

The correct idMSo is "TabMail".